# Send Password using Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

**PROBLEM**

I would like to send the form from Ajax to PHP. My Ajax reaches the PHP but the last one does not find any index corresponding to the value of the Input Password.
I tried to do a lot of research to understand if and where the problem was but nothing.
Also, I would like to know if Ajax is used correctly in this way, to send not only other forms but also JSON files in the future.

Note: PHP responds in JSON format.

**HTML**

```
  <form action="https://civicsensethecitizen.altervista.org/php/formLogin.php" method="post" id="formLogin">
       <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Accedi</button>
  </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(function()
    {
        $('#formLogin').on('submit', function(event)
        {    
            event.preventDefault();

            var items = $('#formLogin').serialize();

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://civicsensethecitizen.altervista.org/php/formLogin.php',
                data: items,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#formLogin').trigger("reset");

                    var result = JSON.stringify(data.flag);

                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    $('#formLogin').trigger("reset");
                    alert('Connsessione non riuscita');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $connessione = mysqli_connect('localhost','civicsensethecitizen','') or die (mysqli_errno ($connessione). mysqli_error ($connessione));
  $db = mysqli_select_db($connessione, "my_civicsensethecitizen") or die ('Database non trovato!');
  $query = "SELECT Password FROM Ente WHERE Password = '$password' ";
  $risultato = mysqli_query($connessione,$query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  $countRisultato = mysqli_num_rows($risultato); //conta quante righe con quella password sono state trovate 
  if($countRisultato == 1)
  {
    $riga = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $dataJSON = array(
      'url' => 'https://civicsensethecitizen.altervista.org/index.html',
      'flag' => 'true',
      'password' =>'Password',
      'categoria' => $riga["CategoriaAppartenenza"],
      'comune' => $riga["ComuneAppartenenza"],
      'regione' => $riga["Regione"]
    );
  echo json_encode($dataJSON);
  }
  else
  {
     $dataJSON = array('flag' => 'false');

     echo json_encode($countRisultato);
  }
  mysqli_close($connessione);
?>
```

Comment: Always `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before echoing your JSON. Just a tip.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you confirm that your PHP script is receiving the password value? Debug by echoing out the password received: `echo "password received: $password";`

Comment: Thank you. No, PHP does not receive anything unfortunately. Indeed we can say that I get an error on the index "password"

Comment: Try commenting out `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. I tried to insert Header (...) before echoing the JSON. But I still do not receive any data back. I tried to get back with echo: $dataJSON = array('flag' => "$password");       header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
      echo json_encode($dataJSON);